# How to get pitch and yaw angle from the raw IMU data?

Tags: ros, imu, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

Im using the IMU data for some orientation platform purpose. Im able to use the IMU in a ROS massagesses in the Callback like these

```
void imuCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImuConstPtr& msg)
{
  tf::quaternionMsgToTF(msg->orientation, quat);
  tf::Matrix3x3(quat).getRPY(r,p,y);
```

But I would like to check when for example some turn of the platforms occur if its exactly by that yaw and pitch.

For example I wonted to record the start time when my platform is start going up/down the ramp , like this condition

```
if(fabs(p-initial_pitch) >= ramp_ang)
    {
        ramp_pitch = fabs(p-initial_pitch)*57.3;    
        
    }
```

So I wont to check the IMU data if that is ok.

Any help?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69037/how-to-get-pitch-and-yaw-angle-from-the-raw-imu-data?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure I completely understand your question, but I don't think this will work if you want to check if there was a change by any **exact** amount.  If you look at the IMU data you are streaming right now you will almost certainly see some noise even when the IMU is motionless.  As a consequence you are unlikely to ever find that the orientation is exactly some angle; you would have to check that the angle was between some range.

---

Originally posted by [MD_MD](https://answers.ros.org/users/5584/md_md/) with karma: 31 on 2013-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-25**:
Ok. And how to check that the angle was between some range?  I wont to check when my platform go up the ramp ( at some pitch angle let we say 3 deg) really occurs at that pitch (more less). Is it more clear now?

**Comment by [MD_MD](https://answers.ros.org/users/5584/md_md/) on 2013-07-25**:
I would do something like

if(pitch>2.5 && pitch<3.5){
do_something;
}

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-25**:
No. I dont wont to change the code. I just wont to plot my pitch angle getting from IMU data.

**Comment by [MD_MD](https://answers.ros.org/users/5584/md_md/) on 2013-07-25**:
You wil have to change your code in some way if you want it to behave differently.  If you are asking about how to get the data from the IMU I would use an IMU filter like imu_filter_madgwick which will calculate the orientation for you.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-25**:
Ok. But can I get the orientation without IMU filter like imu_filter_madgwick? I mean using the orientation data like
x: 0.00555401947349
y: 0.00845728162676
z: 0.4551037848
w: 0.89038091898
Is it possible?

**Comment by [MD_MD](https://answers.ros.org/users/5584/md_md/) on 2013-07-25**:
Yes, but for the most part IMUs don't give you the orientation directly.  They give information like acceleration and momentum which you then have to process into orientation.  You would have to subscribe to the topic /imu_data or /imu_data_raw and use that.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-25**:
I already subscribe. So with tf::quaternionMsgToTF(msg->orientation, quat);
tf::Matrix3x3(quat).getRPY(r,p,y); Im able to get the roll , pitch and yaw. But Dont know how to use the  orientation raw IMU data. Understand?So how to get the pitch and yzw from the raw IMU orientation x,y,z and w?

**Comment by [MD_MD](https://answers.ros.org/users/5584/md_md/) on 2013-07-25**:
I see what you mean now.  I don't know how to do those calculations myself, I use the IMU filter I previously mentioned to do that for me.  If you insist on not using that package you could look at their source code and implement what they did in your own node.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-25**:
And if I use their package. How to do that? How did you used the IMU filter? Cause the documentation is not so good.

**Comment by [MD_MD](https://answers.ros.org/users/5584/md_md/) on 2013-07-25**:
Follow the instructions on the imu_tools page to install and once you have done that rosrun imu_tools imu_filter_madgwick after your have started your IMU.  It will publish a topic called /imu/data and this will contain orientation.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-25**:
Strange . I installed and compile it with rosmake imu_tools. When I tried to  rosrun imu_tools imu_filter_madgwick i got error massage stack/package imu_tools not found. Whats wrong??

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-25**:
rosmake imu_tools works good and compiled without errors. I have this. Built 54 packages with 0 failures. So why  rosrun imu_tools imu_filter_madgwick is not working?

**Comment by [MD_MD](https://answers.ros.org/users/5584/md_md/) on 2013-07-25**:
I misremembered the name of the node, although it is in thier documentation if you look.  It should be rosrun imu_filter_madgwick imu_filter_node. Let us know if that worked.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-25**:
Ok. Now its works. But strange. I got this massage
INFO] [1374818078.308309568]: Starting ImuFilter
[ INFO] [1374818078.313142482]: Using dt computed from message headers
[ INFO] [1374818078.313186901]: Imu filter gain set to 0.100000
[ INFO] [1374818078.313201876]: Gyro drift bias set to 0.000000

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-25**:
Whats wrong?

**Comment by [MD_MD](https://answers.ros.org/users/5584/md_md/) on 2013-07-25**:
I don't see anything wrong, those message are normal.  Did you try rostopic echo /imu/data? That should show you calculated orientations form the /imu/data_raw channel.  You can use the orientations there to get pitch/yaw/roll.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-25**:
I tried.. Not working ..I got rostopic echo /imu/data
WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.
Is /clock being published?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-25**:
Do I need to remap??Cause my Im topic in bag file is called /raw_imu_throttle

**Comment by [MD_MD](https://answers.ros.org/users/5584/md_md/) on 2013-07-25**:
I am not familiar with the /raw_imu_throttle topic or its message, so I can't say if it will work for you to remap it.  I thought you were working from a "regular" imu that published /imu/data_raw.  It might work if you remap the topic you have to /imu/data_raw, but I'm not sure

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-25**:
I tried to remap but not working

**Comment by [MD_MD](https://answers.ros.org/users/5584/md_md/) on 2013-07-26**:
Straight remapping may not work if the message formats are different.  I am not sure how to help you beyond this because I am not familiar with /raw_imu_throttle messages.